# Consume a web service by a web service via Mule ESB

Tags: java, web-services, mule, anypoint-studio

I have a web service that sends a name to a web service called sayHello(), and receives a String "Hello, name".
I want to change the point-to-point connection to something like this:

web service ---> Mule ESB ---> web service

I wonder how can I do that? I've searched for a long time but I didn't find useful document on this topic. Which endpoints should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Try looking at the documentation first: https://docs.mulesoft.com/

Comment: @hdost thank you for your reply, I've been reading the documentation for several weeks but found nothing. So I came here to see if there are people already using Mule ESB to do this

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of webservice you need to expose and consume:

For **exposing SOAP based webservices**, you can use some strategies,

1) Proxying webservices with Protocol Bridging or WSProxyService

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/proxying-web-services

2) Proxying webservices with CXF

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/proxying-web-services-with-cxf

3) Building a webservice with CXF

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/building-web-services-with-cxf

For **exposing RESTful webservices**, you should design a **RAML** and then use the **APIKit** component

> http://raml.org/
>
> https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/apikit-tutorial

For **consuming SOAP based webservices**, you should use the **Webservice Consumer** component

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/web-service-consumer

For **consuming REST webservices**, you should use the **HTTP Request Connector** :

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-request-connector

So, if you want to expose a SOAP webservice (not a proxy service), that internally consumes a SOAP webservice, you can use:

`HTTPListener->CXF->WebserviceConsumer`

If you want to expose a webservice **proxy** you can use the ProtocolBridging or CXF strategy.

If you want to expose a REST webservice, that internally consumes a REST webservice, you can use:

`HTTPListener->APIKit->HTTPRequest`

And so on..

Answer (score 0):

This describes a scenario that you are trying to fulfill https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/proxying-your-api